# Ruby - update running script

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to break a currently running Ruby script, update it, and then continue running it?

E.g. say you had the script:

```
(0..10).each do |x|
   puts x
end
```

could you interrupt it, modify it so the 2nd line read:

```
   puts x * 2
```

then continue execution?

(assuming we ignore trivial arguments like the interrupt time being too short)

Comment: Have you looked into `load` to reload `.rbs`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to actually stop the process, you can [`trap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Signal.html#method-c-trap) the interrupt signal, write the current progress to a file and then look for that file when starting back up:

```ruby
progress_file = './script_progress.txt'
x = if File.exists?(progress_file)
  File.read(progress_file).to_i
else
  0
end

Signal.trap("INT") {
  File.open(progress_file, 'w') { |f| f.write(x.to_s) }
  exit
}

while x <= 10 do
  puts x
  x += 1

  sleep(1)
end
```

Result:

```
$ rm script_progress.txt 
$ ruby example.rb 
0
1
2
3
^C$ cat script_progress.txt 
4
# modify example.rb here, changing `puts x` to `puts x * 2`
$ ruby example.rb 
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

You could also use [`at_exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) to write the file any time the script exits (even when it just finishes normally):

```
progress_file = './script_progress.txt'
x = if File.exists?(progress_file)
  File.read(progress_file).to_i
else
  0
end

at_exit do
  File.open(progress_file, 'w') { |f| f.write(x.to_s) }
end

while x <= 10 do
  puts x
  x += 1

  sleep(1)
end
```

Result:

```
$ ruby example.rb 
0
1
2
3
4
^Cexample.rb:16:in `sleep': Interrupt
    from example.rb:16:in `<main>'

# modify example.rb to double the output again 
$ ruby example.rb 
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

If you want the process to keep running, but just to be able to toggle different functionally, you can send a custom signal using [`Process.kill`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Process.html#method-c-kill):

```
pid = fork do
  Signal.trap("USR1") {
    $double = !$double
  }

  (0..10).each do |x|
    puts $double ? x * 2 : x

    sleep(1)
  end
end

Process.detach(pid)
sleep(5)
Process.kill("USR1", pid)
sleep(6)
```

Result:

```
$ ruby example.rb 
0
1
2
3
4
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

and you can use that to tell ruby to `load` a file again:

```ruby
File.open('print_number.rb', 'w') do |file|
  file.write <<-contents
def print_number(x)
  puts x
end
contents
end

pid = fork do
  load './print_number.rb'
  Signal.trap("USR1") {
    load './print_number.rb'
  }

  (0..10).each do |x|
    print_number(x)

    sleep(1)
  end
end

Process.detach(pid)
sleep(5)
File.open('print_number.rb', 'w') do |file|
  file.write <<-contents
def print_number(x)
  puts x * 2
end
contents
end
Process.kill("USR1", pid)
sleep(6)
```

Result:

```
$ ruby example.rb 
0
1
2
3
4
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

Comment: There are some crazy hacks! Ruby is awesome :)

Comment: I also stumbled across [this presentation](http://avdi.org/talks/rockymtnruby-2011/things-you-didnt-know-about-exceptions.html) that demonstrates some equally-crazy ideas around flow control - such as overriding the `raise` method, to continue execution where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

[pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) does something kind of like this.

If I have a script `test.rb` like so:

```
require 'pry'

result = []
5.times do |i|
  result << "#{i}"
  binding.pry if i == 2
end

puts "result is ", result.join(",")
```

Then at the 3th iteration it will pause at a breakpoint where I can type in commands. If I enter

```
edit test.rb
```

then `$EDITOR` (or nano) will open and I can change the source code. When I exit the text editor, pry will be at the same breakpoint, but will have re-run the existing code up to then using the modified code. This is a kind of sub-shell, and exiting it will bring back the original breakpoint with the original code. After exiting this second breakpoint, I am returned to bash and my edits to the file have been persisted.

Instead of passing a path to `edit`, you can also pass a method name, but it has the same effect (a sub-shell). So in either case, with the code above, if I changed

```
result << "#{i}"
```

to

```
result << "#{i}*"
```

, I would see either `result is 0,1,2,3,4` or `result is 0*,1*,2*,3*,4*`, but not `result is 0,1,2,3*,4*`.

Also, in pry it's possible to edit local variables easily in a breakpoint. for example:

```
require 'pry'

a = 1
binding.pry
puts a
```

If I type `a = 2` and then `control+d` to exit the breakpoint, the program prints `2` like expected. You could also use runtime metaprogramming to override methods, instance variables, etc.